# Using HashSet for duplicate check and convert it back to List

Tags: java

**The following code checks for the duplicates using List**

```
public List<Person> getGroupMembers() {
        final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>(groupMembers.size());
        for (GroupMember member : groupMembers) {
            if (member.getPerson() != null && !member.getPerson().isDeleted()) {
                persons.add(member.getPerson());
                for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < persons.size(); j++) {
                        if (persons.get(i).equals(persons.get(j))) {
                            persons.remove(j);
                            i = 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return persons;
    }

**Now for checking the duplicity I have to use Set Collection and convert it to List
```

for that I have made the changes as below**

```
public List<Person> getGroupMembers() {
        final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>(groupMembers.size());
        final HashSet<Person> setPersons = new HashSet<Person> ();
        for (GroupMember member : groupMembers) {
            if (member.getPerson() != null && !member.getPerson().isDeleted()) {
                setPersons.add(member.getPerson());
                persons.addAll(setPersons);
           }
        }
        return persons;
    }
```

**However above code doesnt work as expected, please suggest**

Comment: What are your expectations?

Comment: Did you override hashCode() and equals()?

Comment: Don't you want to call `persons.addAll(setPersons);` outside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing duplicates from a list is a one-line operation:

```
persons = new ArrayList<Person>(new LinkedHashSet<Person>(persons));
```

Using a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet` will preserve order.

Of course you'd have to remove the `final` modifier from the variable declaration of `persons`, but you should anyway because it isn't necessary and just creates "code noise".

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not eliminate duplicates because it only adds items to `setPersons`, but never checks it for the presence of a person that you are about to add to the set (and to the list). You should also be adding to the list a single person at a time, not all persons that you have found so far.

Add code that verifies that the person is not in the set already to fix this problem, like this:

```
Person p = member.getPerson();
if (p != null && !p.isDeleted() && setPersons.add(p)) {
    persons.add(p);
}
```

Note how `setPersons.add(p)` is used in the `if` condition. Set's `add` returns `true` if the set did not already contain the member, so the above code makes sure that the person will not be added to the list more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You should call:

```
persons.addAll(setPersons);
```

outside of your:

```
for (GroupMember member : groupMembers)
```

This should work, but I cannot test it right now.

```
public List<Person> getGroupMembers() {
    HashSet<Person> setPersons = new HashSet<Person>();

    for (GroupMember member : groupMembers) {
        if (member.getPerson() != null && !member.getPerson().isDeleted()) {
            setPersons.add(member.getPerson());
       }
    }

    return new ArrayList<Person>(setPersons);
}
```

Since `Set` extends `Collection`, you can pass the whole `HashSet` to the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
/**
 *  Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection,
 *  in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.
 */
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

You can view the official tutorial on `Collections` here: [**Oracle: Java Collections**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

And more specifically: [**Set Implementations**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/set.html)

Comment: Thank you , i get the desired result.